# Auto delete data from a table?

Tags: sql, reactjs, graphql, delete-operator, hasura

I have field 'Timer' and 'Name' in a Table. I want to set it up as when a row is added to that table. The row should autodelete after the timer runs out. How can I set it up? I'm using Hasura as my GraphQL client and having a React Application?

Comment: Please share what you have attempted so far. Wouldn't a basic `setTimeOut` and a delete mutation help?

Comment: How does setTimeOut work? How does my Name column knows that it has to autodelete after the Timer runs out. Should I also keep a created_at field to keep track of the timer?

Comment: Can I do it in my graphql client itself?

Comment: You will need to explain more in your question, answering that with only this much information could lead to incorrect results / bad decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of `timer` you may want to go with something like `expires` as you can have 1 field to track this functionality. If you have a `created_at` anyway, there is no real functional difference.

You have two main options here.

1: you can have a Hasura [cron trigger](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/scheduled-triggers/create-cron-trigger.html#creating-cron-trigger) that fires every X amount of time and checks for `now()` > `expires` (or > `created_at + timer` etc...) and deletes those. You will have to write some code somewhere to run when this webhook is called. This can be a good serverless use case. There are examples and codegen tools. See more in the docs.

2: you can track a [view](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/guides/postgres/views.html#id1) with a `where` clause that checks this condition. This won't actually delete the records from your db. But the view with work as though you did delete. This may be a good thing or a bad thing depending on your needs...